# Removing a number, after randomly picking it from a list

Tags: c#

I'm making a little bingo game where I have a list of numbers (1-90). I have it to randomly pick a number, but how do I remove that number after I have randomly chosen it?

This is my attempt so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int r = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Number_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<int> BingoNumbers = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 91; i++)
        {
            BingoNumbers.Add(i);
        }

        r = random.Next(BingoNumbers.Count);
        BingoNumbers.RemoveAt(r);
        RichTextBox1.Text = BingoNumbers[r].ToString();
        RichTextBox2.Text = BingoNumbers[r].ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: And if you want numbers from 1 to 90, start looping at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: As a side note (in addition to solution @GrantWinney provides above), this doesn't persist any state between button clicks. You generate a brand new list of BingoNumbers every click. Removing a value from the list won't have any effect on application state.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you click on that button, your list gets refilled with all 90 numbers. I guess the it should contain one less number with every click, yes?

Then you need to instantiate it outside your click method.

```
List<int> BingoNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 90).ToList();

private void btn_Number_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int r = BingoNumbers.OrderBy(bn => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
    BingoNumbers.Remove(r);
    RichTextBox1.Text = BingoNumbers[r].ToString();
    RichTextBox2.Text = BingoNumbers[r].ToString();
}
```

I've also removed the Random variable, and replaced it with some LINQ magic, which orders your remaining Bingo numbers by a random factor and takes the first argument - and removes it.
If Bingonumbers is empty it will just return 0.

If you want to implement real shuffling, you could go for the Fisher-Yates-Shuffle:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
//Fisher-Yates-shuffle
for (int x = BingoNumbers.Count - 1; x > 0; x--)
{
    int y = rnd.Next(x + 1);
    //Swapping 
    int temp = BingoNumbers[x];
    BingoNumbers[x] = BingoNumbers[y];
    BingoNumbers[y] = temp;
}
//take the first item out of the shuffled list
int r = BingoNumbers[0];
//remove item
BingoNumbers.Remove(r);
```

Comment: Thanks, I only just noticed what i was doing with the button, I feel like such a cluts now -.- :( I have no clue what LINQ is soo the whole int r = line makes very little sense. but thanks for a very quick reply.

Comment: note it could also be done to perform the Guid-based shuffle within the creation of the list itself, if speed is an issue

Comment: Hi, so I tried your whole code you mentioned above today, and i kept getting an error which I am unsure how to fix?

"A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: That is saying, that in you are accessing an index [x] that doesnt exist. You might want to debug your code and see where it excactly occurs. So set a breakpoint and hop into it.

Comment: If you can get to 20 reputation, we can discuss this in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c. Until then you'll have to learn how to debug code I'm afraid, because this is a very basic error, which everyone should be able to solve. Alternativly you can always edit your question and attach your actual code.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the issue, I was skatter brains that day and when i took a little break I found the problem but I have come across a new one, which I don't think is so easily solvable, the issue at hand is impossible to explain without someone having my "full" code rather than a snippet of it.

Comment: Ask a new question - Thats what SO is for.